# Force browser to remember several form values

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the following form:

```html
<form  method="post" autocomplete="on">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Site" name="Site" autocomplete="on" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="User" name="User" id="second" autocomplete="on" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Pass" name="Pass" id="fourth" autocomplete="on" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Station" name="Station" id="third" autocomplete="on" />
    <button>login</button>
</form>
```

The browser remembers user and password, but not site and station.
Is there a way to force the browser to remember ALL values?

Comment: Probably the browser's Password Manager remembers the user name and password. I don't think that you can trick the Password Manager into storing additional data. How about using cookies?

Comment: In fact, browser remembers the form inputs that you put "name" attribute

Comment: When you say "Remember", do you mean that it remembers the entered values in the auto complete history or that the values are automatically filled when loading the page?

Comment: Your browser will remember the values so they're available for autocomplete. Are you looking for a solution where these values get filled out automatically as well?

Comment: Yes - i am looking for the auto-fill as well.

Comment: @capcapdk Then you should probably have a look at solutions using Cookies or Local Storage, depending on what your exact requirements are.

Comment: Force browser to remember? What a fantastic line sire! You cannot force the user to use auto fill etc, use cookies or localstorage like LuudJacobs suggested.